# Can Text fit perfectly into a Shape?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to work our if it's possible to display text in a `Shape` so that the text it not rectangular but the same as the shape it's self.

I have tried

```
    Text(loremIpsum)
        .font(Font.system(size: 14))
        .clipShape(Circle())
```

which the result was that I'm not seeing new lines when text reaches the edge of the shape.

[image: circular text which doesn't have all the text visbile]

I then tried to use the circle first and add text to that but that resulted in text appearing outside the circle.

```
    Circle()
        .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
        .padding(6)
        .overlay(
            Text(loremIpsum)
            .font(Font.system(size: 14))
        )
```

[image: circle with text appearing from the side]

I'm wanting to achieve Text that fits perfectly into whatever `Shape` I use. Is this possible?

The question suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67029483/how-to-have-text-fit-within-boundaries-of-circular-shape-image-swiftui) does not answer my question sadly.  hat just fits text into a `Shape` but still retains a rectangular frame. I'm trying to make text exactly match the shape I am placing it in.

Comment: You can achieve by UIKit https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613814/14733292

Comment: what I'm trying to do is set myself learning exercises to solve problems in SwiftUI rather than UIKit.  Whilst the link looks useful it seems it will be just a circle rather than any `Shape`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have text fit within boundaries of circular shape/image SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67029483/how-to-have-text-fit-within-boundaries-of-circular-shape-image-swiftui)

Comment: It did not sadly.  The text remains in that example the text is still in a rectangle frame and not matching that of the `Shape` I use